# Trivago hotels price checker

Tags: python, beginner, web-scraping

I've decided to write my first project in Python. I would like to hear some opinion from you.

**Description of the script:**

- Generate Trivago URLs for 5 star hotels in specified city.
- Scrape these URLs to get prices.
- Save results as SQL queries in text file
- Execute queries from text file to upload results to database.

**Settings:**

- The date from which the script is going to check prices.
- Number of days to check.
- City to check.
- Name of file with results of the script.

I wrote this script to learn how website scraping in Python works, and how to use SQL. I also wanted to learn something about object-oriented programming.

```
__author__ = ''

import datetime
import pymysql
import lxml.html as lh
import re
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

class TrivagoPriceChecker():
    from_year = ''
    from_month = ''
    from_day = ''
    days_number = ''
    city_id = ''
    hotel_id = ''
    result_file = ''
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    def __init__(self):
        print("Trivago Price Checker ver 1.0")

    def generate_url(self):
        from_date = datetime.date(int(self.from_year), int(self.from_month), int(self.from_day))
        to_date = datetime.date(int(self.from_year),int(self.from_month),int(self.from_day)) + datetime.timedelta(days=int(self.days_number))
        url_list = []
        while(from_date < to_date):
            day_plus = from_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            url = 'http://www.trivago.pl/?aDateRange%5Barr%5D=' + str(from_date) + '&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D=' + str(day_plus) + '&iRoomType=7&iPathId=' + str(self.city_id) + '&iGeoDistanceItem=' + str(self.hotel_id) + '&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&'
            url_list.append(url)
            from_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        return url_list

    def get_hotel_price(self, hotel_url):
        self.browser.get(hotel_url)
        content = self.browser.page_source
        website = lh.fromstring(content)
        for price in website.xpath('//*[@id="js_item_' + str(self.hotel_id) + '"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]'):
            return price.text

    def save_result(self):
        date = datetime.date(int(self.from_year), int(self.from_month), int(self.from_day))
        file = open(self.result_file, "a")
        counter = 1
        for result in self.generate_url():
            try:
                price = self.get_hotel_price(result).strip()
                price = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', price)
                sql_query = "INSERT INTO prices (hotel, city, adate, price) VALUES('" + str(self.hotel_id) +"','" + str(self.city_id) + "','" + str(date) + "','" + str(price) + "');"
                file.write(sql_query)
                file.write('\n')
                print('[' + str(counter) + '/' + str(self.days_number) + '] Hotel ID: ' + str(self.hotel_id))
            except AttributeError:
                print('[' + str(counter) + '/' + str(self.days_number) + '] Hotel ID: ' + str(self.hotel_id) + ' Sold out!')
            counter += 1
            date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        file.close()

poland = {
        "poznan": {"city_id": 86470, "hotel_id": [1711505, 163780, 932461, 1164703]},
        "warszawa": {"city_id": 86484, "hotel_id": [1503333, 93311, 93181, 93268, 106958, 106956, 127649, 106801, 107386, 93245, 154078, 107032]},
        "sopot": {"city_id": 95266, "hotel_id": [228481, 164126, 922891]},
        "gdansk": {"city_id": 86490, "hotel_id": [102961, 1008151, 102944, 1503323]},
        "krakow": {"city_id": 86473, "hotel_id": [931575, 925925, 102937, 148894, 125181, 930571, 114768, 125763, 106926, 102947, 131257]},
        "wroclaw": {"city_id": 86485, "hotel_id": [122767, 123690, 2873646, 1300328, 1511989, 121719]},
        "ilawa": {"city_id": 110111, "hotel_id": [2728378]},
        "bydgoszcz": {"city_id": 86475, "hotel_id": [936931]},
        "kolobrzeg": {"city_id": 114376, "hotel_id": [1288624, 1393804, 3185658, 1217228]},
        "mikolajki": {"city_id": 110236, "hotel_id": [2873760]},
        "rzeszow": {"city_id": 86472, "hotel_id": [2591078]},
        "zakopane": {"city_id": 112161, "hotel_id": [408841, 1828491, 320661]},
        "ostroda": {"city_id": 110301, "hotel_id": [966969]},
        "czeladz": {"city_id": 458329, "hotel_id": [2030401]},
        "gietrzwald": {"city_id": 110071, "hotel_id": [2733447]},
        "krynica_zdroj": {"city_id": 111696, "hotel_id": [1226658]},
        "tychy": {"city_id": 86502, "hotel_id": [164039]},
        "kielce": {"city_id": 86471, "hotel_id": [1941137]},
        "miedziana_gora": {"city_id": 470673, "hotel_id": [2175600]},
        "brojce": {"city_id": 467917, "hotel_id": [412116]},
        "ustka": {"city_id": 93762, "hotel_id": [3082744]},
        "lublin": {"city_id": 86481, "hotel_id": [3083850]},
        "choczewo": {"city_id": 113541, "hotel_id": [3135678]},
        "dziwnow": {"city_id": 114306, "hotel_id": [3213582]},
        "ustron": {"city_id": 114126, "hotel_id": [966089]},
        "szczawnica": {"city_id": 112051, "hotel_id": [1259175]}}

def check_city(from_year, from_month, from_day, days_number, city, result_file):
    worker = TrivagoPriceChecker()
    worker.from_year = from_year
    worker.from_month = from_month
    worker.from_day = from_day
    worker.days_number = days_number
    worker.result_file = result_file
    if city in poland:
        worker.city_id = poland[city]["city_id"]
        print(worker.city_id)
        for x in poland[city]["hotel_id"]:
            worker.hotel_id = x
            worker.save_result()
    else:
        print("City not found!")
        exit()

def export_results(db_host, db_port, db_user, db_password, db_name, query_file):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host=str(db_host), port=db_port, user=str(db_user), passwd=str(db_password), db=str(db_name))
    query = connection.cursor()
    file = open(query_file,"r")
    progress = 0
    for line in file:
        try:
            query.execute(line)
            progress += 1
            print(progress)
        except:
            pass
    connection.commit()
    file.close()
    connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 7:
        check_city(str(sys.argv[1]), str(sys.argv[2]), str(sys.argv[3]), str(sys.argv[4]), str(sys.argv[5]), str(sys.argv[6]))
    else:
        print("Example usage: main.py 2015 02 01 30 sopot sopot.txt")
```

Comment: Do you have this working in software or a spreadsheet or something? Could I see it working? Regards
Jamie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Style and bad pracitces

Even ignoring Caridorc's point about splitting the `import`s, they aren't alphabetical. They should be.

***Wrap your lines!*** There is no reason to even *consider* a 265-character long line.

Stop converting: you're going backa and forth with datatypes like no tomorrow. There's no reason for `from_year` to ever be a string if it's required to be a valid integer. Convert once and keep it so.

You even do

```
str(sys.argv[1]), str(sys.argv[2]), str(sys.argv[3]), str(sys.argv[4]), str(sys.argv[5]), str(sys.argv[6])
```

despite each argument already being a string! Really you should be doing

```
int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), int(sys.argv[3]), int(sys.argv[4]), sys.argv[5], sys.argv[6]
```

!

*Plurals*. `hotel_ids`, not `hotel_id`. `generate_urls`, not `generate_url`.

`__init__` is your initializer. Let it initialize. Don't do this monstrosity:

```
worker = TrivagoPriceChecker()
worker.from_year = from_year
worker.from_month = from_month
worker.from_day = from_day
worker.days_number = days_number
worker.result_file = result_file
```

It should be

```
worker = TrivagoPriceChecker(from_year, from_month, from_day, days_number, result_file)
```

#### Globals!

This is important enough to get its own section. When you do

```
class TrivagoPriceChecker():
    from_year = ''
    from_month = ''
    from_day = ''
    days_number = ''
    city_id = ''
    hotel_id = ''
    result_file = ''
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

you make a particularly evil type of global: one that can be shadowed at any time by any assignment statement to it through `self`. You don't need these "default"s at all: just make a proper `__init__`. Even if you did want defaults like these, you'd want to set them in `__init__`.

Even if you *think* you want a global `browser`, you probably want it shared manually for extensibility in the future.

#### Programming `with` grace

Files [and `pymysql`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L700) support `with`. Use

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host=db_host, port=db_port, user=db_user, passwd=db_password, db=db_name)
with connection as query, open(query_file, "r") as file:
    progress = 0
    for line in file:
        try:
            query.execute(line)
            progress += 1
            print(progress)
        except:
            pass
```

Also consider `enumerate`

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host=db_host, port=db_port, user=db_user, passwd=db_password, db=db_name)
with connection as query, open(query_file, "r") as file:
    for progress, line in enumerate(file):
        try:
            query.execute(line)
            print(progress)
        except:
            pass
```

Also, reduce the "area" of the `try` and the number of things it catches. I see that [stupid exceptions](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L273) are thrown, but you should at least avoid catching `BaseException` (which includes things like `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`) and just do

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host=db_host, port=db_port, user=db_user, passwd=db_password, db=db_name)
with connection as query, open(query_file, "r") as file:
    for progress, line in enumerate(file):
        try:
            query.execute(line)
        except Exception:
            pass

        print(progress)
```

#### For that matter: exceptions

Don't ever do this:

```
if city in poland:
    # code
else:
    print("City not found!")
    exit()
```

Not only are you hiding the error by separating it from the condition that triggers it, you're calling `exit` directly! You're even [calling the wrong `exit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501121/the-difference-between-exit-and-sys-exit-in-python)! Do:

```
if city not in poland:
    raise ValueError("City not found!")

# code
```

When you do

```
except AttributeError:
```

there's a large block of code that could be at fault. Use

```
try:
    # small piece of code
except AttributeError:
    # ...
else:
    # rest of code
```

to narrow this down to something maintainable. In this case, you shouldn't even be using `try ... except`.

#### DRY, not DRY DRY

You have, after prior simplification:

```
from_date = datetime.date(self.from_year, self.from_month, self.from_day)
to_date = datetime.date(self.from_year, self.from_month, self.from_day) + datetime.timedelta(days=self.days_number)
```

Why? This should just be

```
from_date = datetime.date(self.from_year, self.from_month, self.from_day)
to_date = from_date + datetime.timedelta(days=self.days_number)
```

In `save_result` you again do

```
date = datetime.date(self.from_year, self.from_month, self.from_day)
```

This is silly; you call this a lot. In `__init__`, just initialize `self.from_date` and `self.to_date` and drop the other nonsense.

Don't

```
date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

use

```
date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

You do this just above; surely you know of it.

Use formatting instead of `str(a) + 'xxx' + str(b) + 'xxx' + ...`:

```
sql_query = (
    "INSERT INTO prices (hotel, city, adate, price)"
    "VALUES('{self.hotel_id}'','{self.city_id}','{date}','{price}');"
).format(self=self, date=date, price=price)
```

#### Which brings me to...

**SQL INJECTION!**

You should escape. The simple way is just

```
sql_query = (
    "INSERT INTO prices (hotel, city, adate, price)"
    "VALUES('{hotel_id}'','{city_id}','{date}','{price}');"
).format(
    hotel_id=pymysql.escape_string(self.hotel_id),
    city_id=pymysql.escape_string(self.city_id),
    date=date,
    price=price
)
```

In reality, any executing query should use better mechanisms (like interpolating directly with `cursor.execute`) but you're writing to a file so this isn't as easy.

#### And finally

You pass `hotel_id` as a parameter to `save_result` by setting an instance variable. This is ugly; just pass a parameter. `city_id` should probably passed the same way for symmetry.

I've done a little more cleaning and came up with this.

```
__author__ = 'Mateusz Ostaszewski'

import datetime
import lxml.html as lh
import re
import sys

import pymysql
from selenium import webdriver


class  TrivagoPriceChecker:
    def __init__(self, browser, year, month, day, days_number, result_file):
        print("Trivago Price Checker ver 1.0")

        self.browser = browser
        self.from_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
        self.days_number = days_number
        self.result_file = result_file

    def generate_urls(self, city_id, hotel_id):
        url = (
            "http://www.trivago.pl/"
            "?aDateRange%5Barr%5D={}"
            "&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D={}"
            "&iRoomType=7&iPathId={}"
            "&iGeoDistanceItem={}"
            "&iViewType=0"
            "&bIsSeoPage=false"
            "&bIsSitemap=false"
        )

        def make_url(day_num):
            day = self.from_date + datetime.timedelta(days=day_num)
            return day, url.format(day, day, city_id, hotel_id)

        return [make_url(day) for day in range(self.days_number)]

    def get_hotel_price(self, hotel_id, hotel_url):
        self.browser.get(hotel_url)
        content = self.browser.page_source
        website = lh.fromstring(content)

        # Get first if exists, otherwise return None
        for price in website.xpath('//*[@id="js_item_{}"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]'.format(hotel_id)):
            return price.text

    def save_result(self, city_id, hotel_id):
        def esc(x):
            return pymysql.escape_string(str(x))

        query = "INSERT INTO prices (hotel, city, adate, price) VALUES('{}','{}','{{}}','{{}}');\n"
        query = query.format(esc(hotel_id), esc(city_id))

        with open(self.result_file, "a") as file:
            for day, result in self.generate_urls(city_id, hotel_id):
                price = self.get_hotel_price(hotel_id, result).strip()

                if price is not None:
                    price = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', price)
                    file.write(query.format(esc(day), esc(price)))

                soldout = " Sold out!" if price is None else ""
                print('[{}/{}] Hotel ID: {}{}'.format(day, self.days_number, hotel_id, soldout))

poland = {
    "poznan": {"city_id": 86470, "hotel_ids": [1711505, 163780, 932461, 1164703]},
    "warszawa": {"city_id": 86484, "hotel_ids": [1503333, 93311, 93181, 93268, 106958, 106956,
                                                 127649, 106801, 107386, 93245, 154078, 107032]},
    "sopot": {"city_id": 95266, "hotel_ids": [228481, 164126, 922891]},
    "gdansk": {"city_id": 86490, "hotel_ids": [102961, 1008151, 102944, 1503323]},
    "krakow": {"city_id": 86473, "hotel_ids": [931575, 925925, 102937, 148894, 125181, 930571,
                                               114768, 125763, 106926, 102947, 131257]},
    "wroclaw": {"city_id": 86485, "hotel_ids": [122767, 123690, 2873646, 1300328, 1511989, 121719]},
    "ilawa": {"city_id": 110111, "hotel_ids": [2728378]},
    "bydgoszcz": {"city_id": 86475, "hotel_ids": [936931]},
    "kolobrzeg": {"city_id": 114376, "hotel_ids": [1288624, 1393804, 3185658, 1217228]},
    "mikolajki": {"city_id": 110236, "hotel_ids": [2873760]},
    "rzeszow": {"city_id": 86472, "hotel_ids": [2591078]},
    "zakopane": {"city_id": 112161, "hotel_ids": [408841, 1828491, 320661]},
    "ostroda": {"city_id": 110301, "hotel_ids": [966969]},
    "czeladz": {"city_id": 458329, "hotel_ids": [2030401]},
    "gietrzwald": {"city_id": 110071, "hotel_ids": [2733447]},
    "krynica_zdroj": {"city_id": 111696, "hotel_ids": [1226658]},
    "tychy": {"city_id": 86502, "hotel_ids": [164039]},
    "kielce": {"city_id": 86471, "hotel_ids": [1941137]},
    "miedziana_gora": {"city_id": 470673, "hotel_ids": [2175600]},
    "brojce": {"city_id": 467917, "hotel_ids": [412116]},
    "ustka": {"city_id": 93762, "hotel_ids": [3082744]},
    "lublin": {"city_id": 86481, "hotel_ids": [3083850]},
    "choczewo": {"city_id": 113541, "hotel_ids": [3135678]},
    "dziwnow": {"city_id": 114306, "hotel_ids": [3213582]},
    "ustron": {"city_id": 114126, "hotel_ids": [966089]},
    "szczawnica": {"city_id": 112051, "hotel_ids": [1259175]}
}


def check_city(year, month, day, days_number, city, result_file):
    if city not in poland:
        raise ValueError("City not found!")

    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    worker = TrivagoPriceChecker(browser, year, month, day, days_number, result_file)

    city_id = poland[city]["city_id"]
    print(city_id)

    for hotel_id in poland[city]["hotel_ids"]:
        worker.save_result(city_id, hotel_id)


def export_results(db_host, db_port, db_user, db_password, db_name, query_file):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host=db_host, port=db_port, user=db_user, passwd=db_password, db=db_name)
    with connection as query, open(query_file, "r") as file:
        for progress, line in enumerate(file):
            try:
                query.execute(line)
            except Exception:
                pass

            print(progress)


def main():
    try:
        _, year, month, day, days_number, city, result_file = sys.argv
    except ValueError:
        raise SystemExit("Example usage: main.py 2015 02 01 30 sopot sopot.txt")

    check_city(int(year), int(month), int(day), int(days_number), city, result_file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank You so much, i really appreciate it! Thanks to You i will learn how to make not any of these mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 5):

```
try:
    query.execute(line)
    progress += 1
    print(progress)
except:
    pass
```

Here you used a bare (with nothing next to it) except, this is considered bad practice because if an unexpected error happens, it will be silently ignored, instead use;

```
except TheExceptionIThinkWillHappen:
```

---

```
print("City not found!")
exit()
```

This looks like an error, please use:

```
raise ValueError("City not found")
```

---

<del>Possible bug
---

    for price in website.xpath('//*[@id="js_item_' + str(self.hotel_id) + '"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]'):
        return price.text

This returns only the first price because `return` terminates the function, is this intended or a bug? (If you want all the prices you should use `yield`).</del>

---

If you want to follow PEP8 remember to separate the standard library imports from the third library imports, so you should write:

```
# The other imports

from selenium import webdriver
import pymysql
```

This allows the users of your script to check quickly if they have or not the required 3-rd part modeles.

---

```
    url_list = []
    while(from_date < to_date):
        day_plus = from_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        url = 'http://www.trivago.pl/?aDateRange%5Barr%5D=' + str(from_date) + '&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D=' + str(day_plus) + '&iRoomType=7&iPathId=' + str(self.city_id) + '&iGeoDistanceItem=' + str(self.hotel_id) + '&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&'
        url_list.append(url)
        from_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

In general the `while` loop should be avoided, I would use a for loop:

```
url = "http://www.trivago.pl/?aDateRange%5Barr%5D={}&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D={}&iRoomType=7&iPathId={}&iGeoDistanceItem={}&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&"
url_list = []
day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
for date in range(from_date,to_date,day):
    url_list.append(url.format(date,date + day,
        self.city_id,self.hotel_id))
```

or even (but you may not want to compress so much):

```
return [url.format(date,date + day,
    self.city_id,self.hotel_id) for date in range(from_date,to_date,day)]
```

---

```
for price in website.xpath('//*[@id="js_item_' + str(self.hotel_id) + '"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]'):
    return price.text
```

<del>`return` is executed only once but the `for` loops usually does a thing many times, I would have written:</del>

```
prices = [ price.text for price in website.xpath('//*[@id="js_item_' + str(self.hotel_id) + '"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]')]
return prices[0]
```

so that the reader immediately understands that you want to return only the first item.

Veedrac noted that the solution above is too slow, I think the best thing to do here is just adding a comment to make explicit that you only take one item

```
for price in website.xpath('//*[@id="js_item_' + str(self.hotel_id) + '"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/strong[2]'):
    # Return the first price found ONLY
    return price.text
```

---

```
file = open(self.result_file, "a")
```

This line contains a problem:

<del>1. `file` is a `built-in` never re-assign (give another value to) a built-in</del>  as a comment noted, in Python 3 it is not a built-in so don't worry about shadowing it.

1. Opening and closing manually is obsolete, you should use

:

```
with open(self.result_file,"a") as f:
    # some code
    f.write(value)
```

Closing is handled automatically so you will not be in danger of forgetting it.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I used `except: pass` because sometimes i had SQL connection error (time out etc.). Regarding to a possible bug - it is not a bug, it must get only the first price, because specified hotel is always on first place. What about rest of the code? Am i doing it right? I try to keep PEP8 in my mind.

Comment: @Veedrac Good point about `file`. I replaced the generator with a list, it should work now.

Comment: @Veedrac You are right such a slowdown is not acceptable (by the way, you are teaching me so many things, thanks! :) )

Comment: @Caridorc I don't think you can do `range` on `datetime`s.

Comment: @Caridorc What do You think about possibility to speed this code up? I mean it takes much time to check all of these hotels. The only way I know is to run this script multiple times with other arguments at once but I would like to speed it up in other way. Have You any idea?

Comment: @Veedrac you are right: `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got datetime.date`, but now is late... goodnight.